Subprocess Error When Trying to Pip Install Fastparquet on Windows 10 & Python 3.13
I am trying to pip install Fastparquet and get the error below. I have searched but cannot find anything on this specific issue. I've tried running CMD as administrator but that does not help. I've also tried installing the visual studio build tools and upgrading pip but, again, it has not helped.
C:\Users\james>pip install fastparquet
Collecting fastparquet
  Using cached fastparquet-2024.5.0.tar.gz (466 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [46 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
          ~~~~^^
        File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rd0qa88v\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 334, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rd0qa88v\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 304, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
        File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rd0qa88v\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 522, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rd0qa88v\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 320, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
          ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<string>", line 47, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\subprocess.py", line 395, in call
          with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
               ~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1036, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                              pass_fds, cwd, env,
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          ...<5 lines>...
                              gid, gids, uid, umask,
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                              start_new_session, process_group)
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1548, in _execute_child
          hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                   # no special security
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          ...<4 lines>...
                                   cwd,
                                   ^^^^
                                   startupinfo)
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
      FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 24.2 -> 24.3.1
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.


The project only claims compatibility with Python up to 3.12, it might not be compatible with Python 3.13 yet.
Also, this project has uploaded pre-compiled wheels up to Python 3.12 on PyPI, so if you try with Python 3.12, you'll see pip download the pre-compiled fastparquet-2024.5.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl instead of just the source tar ball fastparquet-2024.5.0.tar.gz.
When I ran pip install fastparquet on Win 11 with Python 3.12, installation succeeded. When I ran it on Python 3.13 like you did, it also failed for me.
Refs:

Project page on PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/fastparquet/
Download files: https://pypi.org/project/fastparquet/#files

PS: the project is planning to fix this. See https://github.com/dask/fastparquet/issues/942

Wheel is out now
